# Colorbox of page width, INCLUDING margins

Tags: color, margins, fancyhdr

I want to make a header like on the picture below:

[image]

But I don't know how to force colorbox to overflaw in the margin.
The best I got is:

[image]

I try to use `\hspace` but it only moves the text:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[default]{raleway}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{layout}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,100,200}

\fboxsep0pt

\setlength{\hoffset}{-26pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{-36pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{10pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{10pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{100pt}
\setlength{\headwidth}{451pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{30pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{678pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{451pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{10pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{26pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{10pt}

\lhead{
\colorbox{myblue}{\parbox[b]{21cm}{\Huge Some text in my header.}}
}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\noindent Text of my document.
\end{document}
```

And when I tried with `hspace`:

```
\colorbox{myblue}{\hspace{-50pt}\parbox[b]{21cm}{\Huge Some text in my header.}}
```

I also tried to put `\hspace` before `\colorbox` but in this case, it have no effects.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Sorry for this, I edit the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to calculate where you are on the page in order to "jump around" (left/right) correctly. For that you can save the current left-margin position using [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor,zref-savepos}
\AtBeginDocument{\zsavepos{lmarginmark}}% Store left margin mark
\fancyhf{}
\makeatletter
\lhead{\leavevmode\rlap{%
  \hspace*{-\zposx{lmarginmark}sp}% Adjust to left side of page
  \colorbox{blue}{% blue box
    \makebox[\dimexpr\pdfpagewidth-2\fboxsep][l]{% blue box width
      \hspace*{\zposx{lmarginmark}sp}% Shift back to left margin
      Some header}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\noindent Text of my document.
\end{document}
```

I've included calculations that use `\fboxsep`, although it seems like you're setting these to `0pt`

Comment: Thanks for your reply: it show me that I must use `hspace*` and not `hspace` before the `\colorbox`. And also thanks for the method to calculate the actual margin, etc.

Answer (score 6):

If you like, there is a solution using the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[default]{raleway}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{layout}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,100,200}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\fboxsep0pt

\setlength{\hoffset}{-26pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{-36pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{10pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{10pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{100pt}
\setlength{\headwidth}{451pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{30pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{678pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{451pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{10pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{26pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{10pt}

\lhead{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[size=tight,oversize,
  sharp corners,
  colback=myblue,
  colframe=myblue,
  left=56pt,
  right=90pt,
  fontupper=\Huge]
Some text in my header.
\end{tcolorbox}}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\noindent Text of my document.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for fun I made an alternative with more space above and below the text and a gradient:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[default]{raleway}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{layout}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,100,200}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\fboxsep0pt

\setlength{\hoffset}{-26pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{-36pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{10pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{10pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{100pt}
\setlength{\headwidth}{451pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{30pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{678pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{451pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{10pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{26pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{10pt}

\lhead{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[size=tight,oversize,
  sharp corners,
  enhanced,
  interior style={top color=myblue!50!white,bottom color=myblue},
  colframe=myblue,
  colupper=myblue!20!white,
  left=56pt,
  right=90pt,
  bottom=4pt,
  top=20pt,
  fontupper=\Huge]
Some text in my header.
\end{tcolorbox}}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\noindent Text of my document.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer: I like the idea of a gradient :)